# How can I make Excel automatically partition a graph into segments?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to analyze some existing graphs in Excel worksheets.  They all represent temperature *vs.* time profiles similar to the one in the below below example, encompassing the following six stages:

- stage 1: heating
- stage 2: slow or no further heating from the end of stage 1; temperature is approximately steady at "temp 1".
- stage 3: first cooling step (to be modeled automatically modeled via a linear equation)
- stage 4: temperature approximately steady at "temp 2".
- stage 5: second cooling, down to the final temperature (also automatically modeled via a linear equation).
- stage 6: temperature approximately steady at the final temperature, "temp 3"

How can I make Excel compute the three plateau temperatures and the parameters of linear fits to the two cooling stages, such that I can reuse the solution for all my graphs?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFh3H.png]

Comment: I think you could divide it with Piecewise and plotting it, making sure your function is contiguous. You could also have some help on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/). And please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Link to the [Math Community Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427016/data-analysing-graphs-from-excel) to answer the Math question and here (SO) for Excel Functions and VBA.